# Code creates an exception, know as "overflow encountered in exp"

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, sigmoid

I have created a neural network to predict the value which will take 3 input values and give one output with 2 middle layers. But when it is run, it gives and exception in the function. I'm expecting a value around between 1-15 as the final output.
This is my code for the function

```
        def nonlinear(facts, derive = False):
        if(derive == True):
            return facts*(1-facts)
        else:
            return 1/(1+pckg.exp(-facts))
```

Weights I have created

```
        weight1 = 2*pckg.random.random((3,4))-1
        weight2 = 2*pckg.random.random((4,1))-1
```

Here is the rest of the code where i have used the nonlinear funtion

```
        layer0 = facts;
        layer1 = nonlinear(pckg.dot(layer0,weight1))
        layer2 = nonlinear(pckg.dot(layer1,weight2))         
        layer2Value = layer2Error*nonlinear(layer2,derive = True)       
        layer1Value = layer1Error*nonlinear(layer1, derive = True)
```

> Please note that I haven't included the complete code.

This is the exception I get

```
RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in exp return 1/(1+pckg.exp(-facts))
```

Comment: That's a warning rather than an exception, and can possibly simply be ignored: I'd expect your results to still be accurate. Alternatively, have you considered using [`scipy.special.expit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.expit.html)? BTW, what's `pckg`?

Comment: pckg means numpy package. When I execute I always get the same output and that can't be happen. So what should you do? I can give the code if you wanna see it

Comment: Overflow in a line with a division statement suggests a divide by zero error. Check for that.

Comment: Idiomatic import statement for numpy is `import numpy as np`. Usage would then be `np.exp(-facts)`...